# How to create a web-page with pure json in node-red

Tags: html, json, http, node-red

I'm trying to display raw json data from a msg.variable from node-red on a HTML page, preferably on a external website automatically everytime I need.

I've tried using post and get requests on node-red, but reading the docummentation doesn't make anything clear at all for me.

This is the current flow I have:

[image: I have a flow on node-red that starts from MQTT which provides a JSON that makes an INSERT into a database. Then just after it, it makes a SELECT returning the whole table as a JSON from the database and sending back to the MQTT.]

I'd like to create a node that publishes the pure json string after it makes the select on the database, and make it avaliable on the internet, maybe by portfowarding or using a service that hosts jsons automatically.

Comment: This question is far too broad, you need to break it up into different specific questions. Also it really isn't clear what you mean by the first part, do you mean to publish a MQTT message or serve a JSON response to a http request?

Comment: I want to serve a JSON response to a HTTP request.
All I need is to display a HTML page with a json on it

Answer (score 0):

you are probably searching for the template node.llok here https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/nodes